# Share main.ts file in a front-end code base to serve web and mobile clients

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular-cli

I am trying to design a proper folder and code structure for a front-end angular2-based application that would contain a nativescript part for the Android/iOS views, as well as regular DOM stuff for the Web Browser channel.

Starting off the NativeScript boilerplate, I end up with a `main.ts` file that looks like this:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NativeScriptModule],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {}

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

You see, `platformNativeScriptDynamic` is straight up making this file very, very opiniated, as opposed to the regular and usual `platformBrowserDynamic`. Since I want to use only one root folder for all channels (so I can share model and services), how can I design a `main.ts` file (or whatever else I need) so that on one hand, `ng serve` knows where to go, while on the other hand `tns run android` also knows how to run the mobile app?

Comment: There should be different main files for different platforms, I guess it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this approach is convoluted. I think it would work using `environment.ts`  and the `--environment` command line option, however I discovered (and preferred) a plugin that would handle all this internally:

https://github.com/wwwalkerrun/nativescript-ngx-magic

The drawback is that it plugs nativescript into a ng2-cli project. I think if you wish to do the opposite you'd have to fiddle around a bit.